# why does scientific point format not working in visual basic?

Tags: visual-studio

Use the ToString method with a format string to convert the double variable , pi to the string variable , s, in scientific point format and 3 digits of precision.

Comment: s = pi.ToString("F4") this is what I had. and its my first time on here so still haven't figured out everything. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use toFixed(x) method where x is the number of digits after the decimal point.

```js
var pi = 3.14159;
var s = pi.toFixed(3);
console.log(s);
```